# How to synchronize host folder in container folder with Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to know how to synchronize host folder in container folder with Docker.

This is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:carbon

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I have no docker-compose.yml

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 13):

You have to map volume of your docker container directory with host directory.

For example :

```
docker run -v <host_dir>:<container_dir> -other options imagename
```

Here both directory synchronised vice or versa.

Host directory and container directory must be available.

Comment: did you face node_modules not found error because of the mounting

Comment: No @Vallie, I did not face anything like this. I think you can try cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

by mounting volume

docker run -v /host/folder://usr/src/app -it imagename /bash
then you can change inside host folder it will reflect in container as well.